# How to create group by module and submodule .TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

i need help in this situation with Group By:
I have this list

```
role = {
  _id: '1',
  name: 'Dorant',
  description: 'For people',
  organizationid: '-client',
  permissions: [
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Buildings',
      subModule: 'Areas',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Buildings',
      subModule: 'Areas',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetAreas',
      displayName: 'Get All Areas',
      module: 'Buildings',
      subModule: 'OSS',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Buildings',
      subModule: 'FTT',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Users',
      subModule: 'FDD',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Users',
      subModule: 'SCH',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Sites',
      subModule: 'Devices',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Sites',
      subModule: 'Data Sources',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetBuildings',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Sites',
      subModule: 'Systems',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    },
    {
      name: 'GetDiqka',
      displayName: 'Get All Buildings',
      module: 'Sites',
      subModule: 'Systems',
      permissionType: 'READ',
      constraints: [
        {
          constraint: 'AssignedInBuilding',
          isSelected: false
        }
      ],
      dependecies: [],
      isSelected: false
    }
  ]
};
```

Here you see some permissions with theyrs module and submodules.
One module have some submodules and one submodule and some permissions.
I need to group them in some way to make a new array of the model below.
I want to group them somehow to make a array like this:

```
  moduleName: '',
  subModules: [{
    subMOduleName: '',
    permissions: [{
      
    }]
  }];
}`



With the first list
```

Comment: What did you try ? Where are you stuck ?

Answer (score 0):

> Disclaimer : you should show what you have tried and answerers would explain what is wrong. In the absence of code, I will not provide the complete answer because StackOverflow is not intended for that. Instead, I give you the beginning and explain how to continue.

If I understand the model, you have a list of `permissions`. Each contain an object with a module and a submodule and you want to reorganize this by module/submodule.

Start by creating an empty array of modules then iterate on all permissions with a `forEach` :

```js
const modules = [];
role.permissions.forEach((permission) => {
   [...]
   // here, you will populate the array of modules
}
```

Now, the module's name is `permisssion.module`. You want to check if the module is already present in the variable `modules` and add it if it does not exist.

```js
const modules = [];
role.permissions.forEach((permission) => {

  const moduleName = permission.module;

  // Try to get the module. If it does not exist, create it.
  let module = modules.find(m => m.moduleName === moduleName);
  if(!module) {
    module = {
      moduleName: moduleName,
      subModules: []
    }
    modules.push(module);
  }

  /*
   * From this point the variable "module" contains the module and
   * it exists in the array of modules. You will now want to populate
   * its submodules
   * 
   * Same logic goes for submodules
   * Parse module.subModules in order to see if there is a submodule
   * with subModuleName === permission.subModule
   * Create it if it does not exist and push it to the array of subModules
   */
```